# Как в потоке изменять значения глобально переменной?

Tags: java, android

Поток в `onCreate()` устанавливает значение `true`, но после использования потока глобальная переменная отображается как `false`.

Как ее правильно менять в потоке так чтобы после этого у ее была видимость и вне потока (с присвоенными ей данными в потоке)?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    boolean access;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        txt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run(){
                if (checkInternet()) {

                    access = true;

                } else {

                    access = false;

                }
            }
        }).start();


        Log.d("my_tag", "AFTER Thread access is "+access); // show access as "false"


    } 
}
```

Comment: а если переменную пометить как `volatile`

Comment: скорее всего, у вас просто тред не успевает выполниться, поэтому показывается старое значение. Чтобы подождать, пока поток завершиться - выполните метод join() для объекта типа Thread

Comment: если volatile boolean  access;  то  тоже  false

Comment: @AndrewBystrov вывести работу в асинхронный поток и повесить главный поток для ожидания завершения асинхронного? очень хороший совет ..

Comment: то тогда как по другому ?

Comment: @pavlofff нет, вешать основной поток не надо. Надо дождаться, пока текущий выполниться. Не знаю как в андроиде, но, например, в javafx, есть класс Task, у которого есть метод onSuccess, который вызывается как раз после выполнения задачи

Comment: @AndrewBystrov но дело в том, что пока асинхронный  поток не закончит работу, основной будет стоять и ждать завершения, не выполняя кода после `join()`. Тогда вообще выносить в отдельный поток бессмыслено, задачи не будут паралельными. А вот колбэк на завершение второго потока это уже правильное решение, но оно не имеет отношения к прдложенному вами `join()`

Comment: Для Thread'a нет никаких колбеков, поэтому единственное решение - это делать join. Если использовать более высокоуровневое api, то join'a не надо

Answer (score 1):

Так вы не правильно делаете вывод.

Смотрите:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
       ...
    }).start();
```

Тут вы создали поток и он пошел выполняться. И вы сразу же выводите переменную в ДРУГОМ потоке (который является родителям для потока "интернет чекера").

```
 Log.d("my_tag", "AFTER Thread access is "+access); // show access as "false"
```

Вот и получается, что поток запустился, но `checkInternet()` выполниться не успел и вы выводите старое значение. Варианта два - убрать запуск потока, если `checkInternet()` выполняется быстро, то вы только теряете время на запуске потока. Либо если `checkInternet()` и всё что в `run()` выполняется долго, то переместите вывод в сам поток:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run(){
            Log.d("my_tag", "Checking internet..."); 
            if (checkInternet()) {
                access = true;
                Log.d("my_tag", "Okay, internet works fine."); 
            } else {
                access = false;
                Log.d("my_tag", "Fail! Can't connect to internet."); 
            }
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: этот вариант мне не подходит потому-что checkInternet() должен выполнятся в отдельном потоке к тому же access дожна изменится чтобы ее сразу же видел основной поток а тут так не получится придется ждать выполнения этого потока для проверки подключения

Comment: @mtb,  надеюсь Вы понимаете, что проблема в том, что вы проверяете значение переменной до того, как она меняется. Т.е. переменная меняется из отдельного потока, но вы, не дожидаясь ее изменения, берете старое значение.

Comment: меня интересует как синхронизировать это действие без остановки главного потока

Comment: Если вы вызовите join(), как вам посоветовали выше сразу же после вызова start() это будет равносильно выполнению в одном потоке. Только вы ещё потеряете время на запуске потока. В общем эпичная лажа. Имеет смысл, только если вы не хотите блокировать интерфейс. В принципе вы всё правильно делаете, только вывод сделали не там. Все действия нужно проводить в новом потоке. Сразу наперед скажу, захотите манипулировать интерфейсом из другого потока - почитайте про runOnUIThread и postInvalideate, часто новички спотыкаются на этом.

Comment: чем эти методы лучше AsynTask ?

Comment: Тем что AsyncTask это альтернатива Threads, что сделали вы. Я так подозреваю, что под капотом у AsyncTask как раз этот Thread и есть и он по сути обертка над Thread. Хотя могу и ошибаться.

Answer (score 0):

В логах Вы получаете `false` из-за того, что в Вашем случае, переменная изменяет свое значение после того, как Вы выводите ее значение в лог.

Т.е. Вы запускаете поток, потом выводите значение переменной, а только после этого меняете значение этой переменной.

Если Вам нужно проверить наличие интернет-соединения, и, в зависимости от результата выполнить какие-либо действия, можете объявить в классе активити коллбэк:

```
private void onInternetConnectionChecked(boolean isEnabled) {
    // some actions
}
```

И вызывать этот коллбэк из потока, после того, как получите состояние интернет-соединения, например:

```
onInternetConnectionChecked(true);
```

Если в этом коллбэке Вы будете производить манипуляции с UI, то нужно вызвать этот коллбэк в UI-потоке:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        onInternetConnectionChecked(true);
    }
});
```